# Mocking two functions with patch for a unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking, nose

I have a function I want to unit test contains calls two other functions. I am unsure how can I mock both functions at the same time properly using patch. I have provided an example of what I mean below. When I run nosetests, the tests pass but I feel that there must be a cleaner way to do this and I do not really Understand the piece regarding f.close()...

The directory structure looks like this:

```
program/
  program/
    data.py
  tests/
    data_test.py
```

data.py:

```
import cPickle

def write_out(file_path, data):
    f = open(file_path, 'wb')
    cPickle.dump(data, f)
    f.close()
```

data_test.py:

```
from mock import MagicMock, patch

def test_write_out():
    path = '~/collection'
    mock_open = MagicMock()
    mock_pickle = MagicMock()
    f_mock = MagicMock()
    with patch('__builtin__.open', mock_open):
        f = mock_open.return_value
        f.method.return_value = path
        with patch('cPickle.dump', mock_pickle):
            write_out(path, 'data')
            mock_open.assert_called_once_with('~/collection', 'wb')
            f.close.assert_any_call()
            mock_pickle.assert_called_once_with('data', f)
```

Results:

```
$ nosetests
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.008s
OK
```

Answer (score 160, accepted):

You can simplify your test by using the patch decorator and nesting them like so (they are `MagicMock` objects by default):

```
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch('cPickle.dump')
@patch('__builtin__.open')
def test_write_out(mock_open, mock_pickle):
    path = '~/collection'
    f = mock_open.return_value
    f.method.return_value = path
    
    write_out(path, 'data')
    
    mock_open.assert_called_once_with('~/collection', 'wb')
    mock_pickle.assert_called_once_with('data', f)
    f.close.assert_any_call()
```

Calls to a `MagicMock` instance return a new `MagicMock` instance, so you can check that the returned value was called just like any other mocked object. In this case `f` is a `MagicMock` named `'open()'` (try printing `f`).

Comment: In your suggestion, you introduce two parameters, one for each mock. How does python know which is which? I failed to find the answer to this in the docs.

Comment: The decorators are applied bottom-up and the order of the parameters need to match this. See here: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html?highlight=stack#nesting-patch-decorators

Comment: Yes, I've read this, but didn't find it clear enough. Thanks!

Comment: Notice that parameters here are in opposite order in which patches were applied.

Comment: What is `f.method.return_value = path` doing?

Comment: It sets the return value for the method, so every time `f.method()` always returns `path`

Comment: what if my same function i want to mock based on different parameter values? How that works?

Comment: @JayeshDhandha have a look at `side_effect` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide)

Comment: @MattiJohn that to raise exception not mocking same function twice. Is it?

Answer (score 98):

In addition to the response @Matti John you can also use `patch` inside function `test_write_out`:

```
from mock import MagicMock, patch

def test_write_out():
    path = '~/collection'
    with patch('__builtin__.open') as mock_open, \
            patch('cPickle.dump') as mock_pickle:

        f = mock_open.return_value
        ...
```

Answer (score 16):

As of Python 3.10 you can do use [Parenthesized Context Managers](https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html#parenthesized-context-managers) like this

```py
from unittest.mock import patch


def test_write_out():
    with (
        patch('cPickle.dump'),
        patch('__builtin__.open') as open_mock,  # example of using `as`
    ):
        yield
```

Comment: nice!  That's useful for much more than just the current question

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example on how to test raising `ConflictError` in `create_collection` function using mock:

```
import os
from unittest import TestCase
from mock import patch
from ..program.data import ConflictError, create_collection


class TestCreateCollection(TestCase):
    def test_path_exists(self):
        with patch.object(os.path, 'exists') as mock_method:
            mock_method.return_value = True

            self.assertRaises(ConflictError, create_collection, 'test')
```

Please, also see [mock docs](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) and Michael Foord's awesome [introduction to mock](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d3_LdLzWSXQ).

Comment: Thank you for even trying to help me out. This does help me, but I was more focused on how to mock multiple functions using patch. Unfortunately, my question did not make that clear. I have cleaned up the question now.